# How to construct simultaneous equations from two lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

Assume that I want to solve a simultaneous equation below.

\begin{cases}
2x_1+3x_2=5\\
x_1-x_2=0
\end{cases}

First I construct two lists

```
coefs = {{2, 3, 5}, {1, -1, 0}};
vars = Array[x, 2];
```

Note that I feel more comfortable to put the constants `5` and `0` in the coefficient list rather than separating them into another list.

Because I don't know how to construct `equ` from the above lists, I manually construct as follows.

```
equ = 2 x[1] + 3 x[2] == 5 && x[1] - x[2] == 0
```

Finally `equ` is passed to `Solve[equ, vars]`.

## Question

What is the **simplest** way to construct `equ`  from the available two list `coefs` and `vars`?

## Minimal Working Example

The following template will save your typing time.

```
coefs = {{2, 3, 5}, {1, -1, 0}};
vars = Array[x, 2];
equ = 2 x[1] + 3 x[2] == 5 && x[1] - x[2] == 0
Solve[equ, vars]
```

## 1st attempt

```
coefs = {{2, 3, 5}, {1, -1, 0}};
vars = Array[x, 2];
temp1 = {#1, #2} & @@@ coefs.vars
temp2 = Table[temp1[[i]] == coefs[[i, 3]], {i, 1, 2}]
equ = temp2[[1]] && temp2[[2]]
Solve[equ, vars]
```

I also want to know what is the best way to concatenate `temp2` in
`equ = temp2[[1]] && temp2[[2]]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
coefs = {{2, 3, 5}, {1, -1, 0}};
```

Two additional approaches:

**1.** Using the fourth argument of `Array` to do all in a single step:

```
ClearAll[slv]
slv[a_] := Array[x, Length @ a, 1, Solve[Thread[a. {##, -1} == 0], {##}] &]

slv @ coefs
```

> {{x[1] -> 1, x[2] -> 1}}

**2.** Process `coefs` directly into input for [`LinearProgramming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearProgramming.html):

```
ClearAll[lp]
lp[a_] := LinearProgramming[ConstantArray[0, Length@a], Most /@ a, Thread[{Last /@ a, 0}]]

lp @ coefs
```

> {1, 1}

Answer (score 6):

One way might be

```
 eqs = And @@ Thread[coefs[[1 ;; 2, 1 ;; 2]].vars == coefs[[All, 3]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Applying it

```
coefs = {{2, 3, 5}, {1, -1, 0}};
vars = Array[x, 2];
equ = And @@ Thread[coefs[[1 ;; 2, 1 ;; 2]].vars == coefs[[All, 3]]];
Solve[equ, vars]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

If you need to see the equations, use

```
equ = Thread[coefs.Append[vars, -1] == 0]
```

Or, just go straight to the solution

```
Solve[Thread[coefs.Append[vars, -1] == 0], vars]
```